# Active record associations for a User and has many addresses with one marked as primary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to setup my rails models where I have a `User` and they have many `addresses` but one is their primary address. I want to be able to access it like so, `User.first.primary_address_id` and also `User.first.primary_address` to get the associated `Address` model.

Is there a "rails way" to set this up?

I know I could create a `primary_address_id` field for `User` and populate it in an AR callback. But that wouldn't let me do something like `User.first.primary_address`

Or can I create associations as "User has_many Addresses" as well as "User has_one Address"?? or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I could create a primary_address_id field for User and populate it in an AR callback. But that wouldn't let me do something like User.first.primary_address

This is the correct way to do it.

```
User.first.primary_address
```

would return the first user's primary address if they had one or nil if they didn't.

```
#user.rb
has_one :primary_address

#address.rb
attr_accessor :primary #this allows you to have a primary field of the address form

after_save :check_if_primary

def check_if_primary
   user.update_attribute(:primary_address, self) if primary
end
```

Comment: Where do I define it and how does it get associated?

Comment: You'd define it as a has one relationship. Where you define it depends on your use case but if you were to define it as part of your address save you would be right to use a callback. Check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to have a primary_address boolean column in your Address model.

To access the primary address object of the user you could define a primary_address method in the User model :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def primary_address
    addresses.where(:primary_address => true).first
  end
end
```

Since, the primary_address method is an instance method, it would allow you to do

```
User.first.primary_address
```